# How to track ruby lambda/proc calls on newrelic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic, proc

I have a bunch of lambda calls, let's say something like:

```
transactions = []
transactions << [:do_something, ->(input) { ... }]
transactions << [:do_something_else, ->(input) { ... }]

transactions.each { |(name, transaction)| transaction.call(input) }
```

and I'd like to get metrics (timing) on each call as part of the request (this is on top of rails BTW).

I've played around with `MethodTracer`, something like:

```
transactions.each do |(name, transaction)|
  NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer.trace_execution_scoped(name) do
    transaction.call(input)
  end
end
```

But I'm not quite sure the data I'm seeing on newrelic is right since I see the timing on the controller is less than the timing on some lambda/transactions (executed by the controller).

Does anybody knows the right way to trace this?